# android: Google APIs (Android API 13)

Tags: android-emulator, android

I am trying to install Third party add-ons using Android SDK. Below is what I am trying to install.

**Android SDK >> Available packages >> Third party Add-ons >> Google Inc. >> Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 13, revision 1**

It gives me error like this.

```
Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 13, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\google_apis-13_r01.zip (Access is denied)
```

I am not sure what is the problem. Can you please help me to install this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the SDK manager as Administrator for it to install updates otehrwise Windows refuses to let it create files.

Answer (score 2):

I got a way to remove this error. I just applied read & write permissions to `tmp` folder of android sdk, and it worked!

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try moving the SDK out of C:\Program Files (x86)

Answer (score 0):

If your SDK manager is installed as a Eclipse plugin and don't know how to 'run as administrator'. Try go to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk', right click 'SDK Manager.exe' -> 'run as administrator' should solve